# Camera and Photos permission - iOS

Tags: ios

I am trying to test Camera and Photos permission requests.

However, I am running in to the following scenario: I granted permission(permission `notDetermined`), but made a mistake and want to try going through that prompt flow again.

I uninstalled my application and then did a clean XCode build but after the app installs the permissions granted or denied with the previous installation are remembered by the OS in settings app.

Not just camera or notifications, but I have also recently seen that sometimes Location and Notifications permissions are preserved.

Not sure if this is some new behavior with iOS 13, but i swear it didn't act like this before in iOS 12.

Is there a way, for testing purposes to stop the OS from remembering permissions between installs?